# Any free programs to check OS version, browser and screen resolution?

Tags: browser, operating-systems

I am looking for a small, preferably free tool which my non-techie customer can download on their machine and when run, it gives them following

1. OS Name version
2. Browser name, version
3. Screen resolution.

They currently have some problems with my website and I am guessing it has something to do with OS browser combination.

Comment: What about users with multiple browsers? For instance, I have (at least) IE7, FF3.5, Chrome3, Safari4, and Opera10. Which browser would a non-browser-based tool report? Most users of anything other than IE will still have IE installed...

Comment: Er, on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

http://supportdetails.com/

Will pretty much do everything you want :)

Comment: I really liked this one. Do we have a way to attach the resutls with the feedback form, so that i dont have to specifically ask users to open this and type in few information.

Its like whenever user writes to us with some issue, we already know what type of machine/os/browser he is working on

will help us troubleshoot quickly.

Comment: @DavidYell That's almost exactly what I'm looking for. But white label/open source and with auto-send.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your site's users are technically advanced, you can get most of this information from your site logs. Each HTTP request carries the `USER-AGENT` header, which on all major browsers tells you the browser and OS version. This can be spoofed, but again, if your users aren't technically advanced, they won't be spoofing.

That won't tell you screen resolution, though, I don't think. But you can get it via JavaScript on your pages, via the [`screen`](http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/ecmascript/quickref/screen.html) object.

I mention these because in the first one, you may already have the info; and in the second, it's easy to get. Much easier, I suspect, than getting users to download and run a tool...

Answer (score 0):

You can do these things by writing a HTML page with JavaScript unless you have some specific requirement for which you need any free app.

You can get the info in following way:

**OS:**

```
function yourOS() {
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if (ua.indexOf("win") != -1) {
    return "Windows";
} else if (ua.indexOf("mac") != -1) {
    return "Macintosh";
} else if (ua.indexOf("linux") != -1) {
    return "Linux";
} else if (ua.indexOf("x11") != -1) {
    return "Unix";
} else {
    return "Computers";
}
```

}

**Screen Resolution:**

```
(screen.width>=1024) && (screen.height>=768)
```

**Browser:**

```
var browser=navigator.appName;

var b_version=navigator.appVersion;

var version=parseFloat(b_version);
```